# How to recover a runaway emacs?

Tags: osx, quitting, exit

Sometimes I'll open a large structured files (say, JSON) using `json-mode`, but the contents are malformed in some way (or something) and my Emacs session will suddenly spike my CPU to 100% and become unresponsive.  Attempting to quit with `C-g` seems to do nothing.

Is there a graceful way to recover from such a situation? I usually just end up killing my entire emacs process and (in bad cases), editing the `.emacs.desktop` file to omit the problematic buffers.

I'm running GNU Emacs 28.2 on macOS 13.4.1.

Comment: Send in a bug report (`M-x report-emacs-bug`), attaching the file (somehow - maybe as a link if it is really big) that caused the problem. How big is the file? How much memory do you have on your system?

Answer (score 1):

You can try multiple `C-g`.  Better yet, you can try `ESC ESC ESC`.  And you can try `C-]`.  And if Emacs is somewhat responsive you might be able to use `M-x top-level`, to exit all recursive edits.

See the Emacs manual, node [Quitting and Aborting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html).

But if those attempts don't help then you need to kill the Emacs process, I believe. You do that from outside Emacs (using a shell command such as `kill` or a tool such as the MS Windows Task Manager).